# unenforced constraints/possible duplication in my database design?

Tags: database-design, schema

I am trying to store information about a school and the class timetable in a database. The outline is as follows:

'A subject has ~20 lessons, each of which needs to have it's description stored in the database. The topic of each lesson is also kept.

Each topic is also taught by a different teacher(s) - some topics are taught by multiple teachers. Each teacher only teaches a single subject and topic.'

So far I have this:

```
topics:
(id (PK), topic_name)

subjects:
(id (PK), subject_name)

lessons:
(id (PK), lesson_desc, subject_id (FK), topic_id (FK))

teachers:
(id (PK), teacher_name, subject_id (FK), topic_id (FK))

teachers_and_lessons:
(teacher_id (PK), lessons_id (PK))
```

However, my concern is that it does not enforce certain constraints, and information is perhaps being unnecessarily duplicated.

For example, there is no enforced constraint against me adding a (teacher, lesson) pair to `teachers_and_lessons` where the teacher's `subject_id` is 4 but the lesson's `subject_id` is 5.

Assuming the data is valid, you can also infer the the `subject_id` and `topic_id` of the lesson or the teacher by using `teachers_and_lessons` and either the `lessons` or `subjects` table. For example, a teacher with record (1, roger, 1, 2). If the record (1,3) exists in `teachers_and_lessons`, then the lesson with id = 3 must have subject_id = 1 and topic_id = 2. Note also: a lesson or teacher should be able to exist without having been assigned anything.

Does anyone know a  better way of structuring my database? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your model includes referential cycles.  This comes up quite a bit when you're modeling and you haven't worked through the differences between what relationships *exist* and what relationships *are important to your system*.

Without knowing more about your business rules and their justification, I would suggest that you consider dropping `teachers.topic_id` and possibly also `teachers.subject_id`.

Your `lessons` table relates subjects and topics.  Since you have a many-to-many relationship between teachers and lessons, you can use `lessons` (via `teachers_and_lessons`) to tell you which teachers can teach which topics and which subjects.

I doubt that neither `teachers.topic_id` nor `teachers.subject_id` are correct anyway, since this would imply that any given teacher can only teach one topic and one subject.  I don't know about your school, but it sounds much too specialized to me!

---

**Edit: Recognizing Teaching Qualifications**

Based on a comment by OP (below) the question is how can a teacher be recognized as being qualified to teach a topic without there being an actual lesson assignment made (yet)?

**Issue 1: The relationship of topics to subjects:**

It isn't clear from the original question whether topics belong to one subject or possibly to multiple subjects.  If topics (e.g. *fractions*) belong to only one subject (e.g. *math*) then there should be a foreign key like so: `topics.subject_id`.  If this were so, then `lessons.subject_id` would be redundant and could also be dropped.  This would simplify the model and make things much clearer while reducing the risk of inconsistent foreign keys.

**Issue 2: What teachers *can do* vs. what they *are doing*:**

The `teachers_and_lessons` table shows which lessons teachers are actually teaching.  Before this assignment is made, OP would like to be able to record which topics a teacher is qualified to teach.  This could be done with a second M:N intersection, like so:

```
teacher_qualifications:
(teacher_id (PK/FK), topic_id (PK/FK))
```

This design assumes the simplification suggested under *Issue 1*, above.  One potential drawback of this simplistic solution is that there is no constraint against assigning a teacher to teach a lesson for which they are unqualified.  This constraint, if it is important, could be accommodated by replacing the `teacher_qualifications` and the `teachers_and_lessons` tables with new tables as follows:

```
teacher_qualifications:
(qualification_id (PK), teacher_id (FK,UN1), topic_id (FK,UN1))

lesson_instructor:
(qualification_id (PK,FK), lessons_id (PK,FK))
```

Again, these tables assume the simplification from Issue 1.  Even without that simplification, these tables could be amended to use an analogous approach.

Comment: Yes, although it may seem strange, there is a constraint a teacher can only teach one topic and subject for my particular model. I have a question about your suggestion if I may. What If I wanted to add a lecturer to the system and would like to note that they teach the topic 'fractions' in the subject 'math'. It seems like I would be powerless to do this until he was assigned to a lesson

Comment: @rogersmith One of the issues with your model is that it doesn't recognize the relationship between a subject and a topic, unless there is a lesson for it.  See my edit for a possible solution to this.

Comment: You're not going to like this Joel, but topics can belong to multiple subjects haha. Nevermind though, I understand your approach and I'm pretty sure I can make it work. Thank you very much for your help! :)